# How to save class object reference values in SharedPreferences and retrieve it in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, gson

Right now I am trying to store class object value in SharedPreferences and retrieve it. I referred many links still, I am not able to store the object value in it.

Below is my code:

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getContext().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = null;
prefsEditor.putString(json, gson.toJson(object));
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Exception:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in String json = null; ? try String json = "";

Comment: @SuhailMehta you want me to put any method or entire class?

Comment: @SergeyYamshchikov i tried even that by putting String json = gson.toJson(object) instead of null, still i am getting Stackoverflow Exception

Comment: stackOverflow comes when you have cyclic reference in model

Comment: Are you using any other libs , like `ActiveAndroid` ?

Comment: @Rinnegan Naruto oh, sorry, I missunderstand the snippet. The problem usually appear when your object doesn't have no-args constructor.

Comment: @SergeyYamshchikov can you give me any link or sample code

Comment: @Rinnegan Naruto it's requirement from Gson, that Object have to have default constructor without any arguments. All you need it's add it if you don't have one, in other the problems may lay in inner classes and so on, unfortunately gson can't marshull everything without additional job. So, it will be useful if you can post here you object.

Answer (score 0):

The Object need to *implement* **Serializable** so the Gson can convert your Object to string. Something like this:

```
public class User implement Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1234567891234567891L;

  private String name;
  private int age;

  // constructor
  public User(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  // setter and getter.
}
```

Then you can save the object with Gson:

```
User user = new User("Terminator", 50);

SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getContext().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(user);
prefsEditor.putString("User", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```